# How to make object (a mutable stack) thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, scala, thread-safety

How to make Scala object thread-safe.

```
class Stack {
    case class Node(value: Int, var next: Node)

    private var head: Node = null
    private var sz = 0

    def push(newValue: Int) {
        head = Node(newValue, head)
        sz += 1
    }

    def pop() = {
        val oldNode = head
        head = oldNode.next
        oldNode.next = null
        sz -= 1
    }

    def size = sz    //I am accessing sz from two threads
}
```

This class is clearly not threadsafe. I want to make it threadsafe.

Thanks in Advance,

HP

Comment: So, why isn't it threadsafe? What have you tried to make it threadsafe?

Comment: (The issue isn't just with `sz`: remember, it is operations and how they are used that must be atomic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, the easiest way to make this meaningfully thread-safe would be as follows:

```
class Stack {
    case class Node(value: Int, var next: Node)

    private var head: Node = null
    private var sz : Int = 0

    def push(newValue: Int) {
        synchronized {
            head = Node(newValue, head)
            sz += 1
        }
    }

    def pop() : Option[Int] = {
        synchronized {
            if ( sz >= 1 ) {
                val ret = Some(head.value)
                val oldNode = head
                head = oldNode.next
                oldNode.next = null
                sz -= 1
                ret
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }

    def size = synchronized { sz }
}
```

This implementation would allow you to ensure that `push`'s and `pop`'s would be atomic, with `pop` returning a `Some` wrapping the value it removed from the top of the stack or `None` if the stack was already empty.

As a note, access to the size is synchronized, but you have no way of guaranteeing that it will be correct at any point after it is returned, since multiple threads are able to access the stack, potentially altering its size. If you really do need to know the size exactly accurately, you would have to go about this differently, synchronizing on the whole stack when you use it.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge synchronizing when return size would be slightly more accurate, in that it would not return the size in the midst of a push or pop operation, but the value return could be invalidated as soon as it is received, since another thread pushing or popping would not update the value returned by size. I will add it in though, since it is better than nothing.

Comment: Another, more efficient way to implement `size` would be as `def size = sz` and to add the `@volatile` annotation to `sz`.  In this case, `synchronized` is just overkill for field access.

Answer (score 6):

Just because it's fun, you can also make this thread-safe by popping `head` into an AtomicReference and avoiding `synchronized` altogether.  Thusly:

```
final class Stack {
  private val head = new AtomicReference[Node](Nil)

  @tailrec
  def push(newValue: Int) {
    val current = head.get()
    if (!head.compareAndSet(current, Node(newValue, current))) {
      push(newValue)
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  def pop(): Option[Int] = head.get() match {
    case current @ Cons(v, tail) => {
      if (!head.compareAndSet(current, tail))
        pop()
      else
        Some(v)
    }

    case Nil => None
  }

  def size = {
    def loop(node: Node, size: Int): Int = node match {
      case Cons(_, tail) => loop(tail, size + 1)
      case Nil => size
    }

    loop(head.get(), 0)
  }

  private sealed trait Node
  private case class Cons(head: Int, tail: Node) extends Node
  private case object Nil extends Node
}
```

This avoids locking entirely and provides substantially better throughput than the `synchronized` version.  It's worth noting though that this sort of fake thread-safe data structure is rarely a good idea.  Handling synchronization and state management concerns at the level of a data structure is a bit like trying to handle IO exceptions within an XML parser: you're trying to solve the right problem in the wrong place and you don't have the information needed to do that.  For example, the stack above is perfectly safe, but it's certainly not consistent across operations (e.g. you could push and subsequently pop onto a stack and get `None` as a result).

Your better option is to use an immutable stack (like `List`) and throw *that* into an `AtomicReference` if you need shared mutable state.

Comment: I am getting error as Node not defined on line 4. If I define Node as in my program, I get Node already defined. Thanks for the explanation though. That was helpful